# PHP Session & Cookies Interview questionn

Tags: php, session, cookies

This is one of the question that had asked in interview yesterday!

According to my understanding.... When user logged in in web application we start a session and store all the data in $_SESSION array(which is stored on server but not on Cookies)

and cookies is just a local data when we write script for login & Registration form, We don't set any cookies to identify user

If session data is stored on server and not in cookies,

I have my own login registration system at

http://dandnayak.in/lr

1) I first login 2) Clear cookies 3) Refresh 4) I get logged out without even hitting logout button

How do i get logged out from any of current account, when i delete cookies!

$_SESSION & $_COOKIES
What is the difference in this case?

Comment: the session id is kept in a cookie, no cookie = no session id  = no way to identify you

Comment: Think of it like this when the session starts, it gives you a cookie, but now every time the session is validated you have to show the cookie and it has to be the cookie that session(same session id) gave you.

Comment: i guess you didn't get the job ? oh and don't repost, edit (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669237/why-logged-out-from-any-of-current-account-when-i-delete-cookies)

Comment: I cannot understand you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP sessions are saved on server files with name like `sess_some_session_id` (eg: `sess_vu3a4l18bkt24q5qimsav2r7d3`) and this `some_session_id` will be stored on a Cookie variable named `PHPSESSID`. When you clear the 
Cookie, PHP will not be able to identify the session file which belongs to the current user.
That why you are getting logged out

Answer (score 1):

The server stores a cookie on the client that contains an identifier to lookup the data stored on the server, associated to the current client. So while the data itself is not stored in the cookies, a static reference to the data is stored as a "key" in a cookie, to persist data across requests

Here is a good article to explain in a little more depth: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/1/2

Answer (score 0):

This is classic example in application servers.

To answer your question in simple terms,

An Application Server (PHP, ColdFusion,...) hosts many applications at given time. And each application inturn has a session for each user. So, to identify this combination, it stores the session tokens in cookies. When you make a request, it checks the information given in cookies to match with the ones in its session store and let you use the application.

When you delete the cookies, the server has no way to identify if you have a session already or you are doing a fresh login. It chooses the later.

That is the reason, why you get logged out.